# Image to text Python 3.6 error using tesseract and pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, tesseract

I'm trying to use the image_to_string function from pytesseract but can't get to do that.
I've already installed the pytesseract module and the tesseract module but this last one won't seem to work, I have the following code

```
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import time
import sys
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
A=Image.open("C:/Users/Martin/Python/Python36/Tickets/2.jpg")
pytesseract.image_to_string(A)
```

When I run this I get thefollowing error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Martin/Python/Python36/cosa.py", line 9, in <module>
    pytesseract.image_to_string(A)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 193, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 140, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 111, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

So I tried to run import tesseract and this shows up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    import tesseract
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 34
    print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess it's a compatibility problem (I'm using Python 3.6.5 and print is now a function so () is expected) but when i run pip install --upgrade tesseract I get that it's already up to date so I don't know how to make this work. I'm working with Windows 7 64bits.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In your system there's no Tesseract installed.

The package `tesseract` that you have installed with `pip` is [another Python package](https://pypi.org/project/tesseract/) which is not correlated to the Tesseract OCR engine.

You have to install Tesseract following [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#installation) instructions. Then you can use `pytesseract`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this solves your problem because it's windows and error is not English, but for other googlers, if you encounter

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

The ocr needs to be installed separately from the python package from pip:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Will install it into your path.

Answer (score 0):

The ocr needs to be installed separately from the python package from pip:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Comment: He is using Windows so this command doesn't work and I guess you made a mistake it is `apt-get install` instead of `apt`...